# Integrability/measurability of a map to the bounded operators on $L^2$

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

For each $t\in [0,1]$, let $T_t\colon L^2(\mathbb{R})\to L^2(\mathbb{R})$ be the operator that shifts everything to the right by $t$, i.e.
$$T_t f(x)=f(x-t)$$
for all $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Then $t\mapsto T_t$ defines a map
$$\gamma\colon[0,1]\to\mathcal{B}(L^2(\mathbb{R})).$$
Note that $\gamma$ is not continuous.

**Question:** Is $\gamma$ Bochner-integrable, i.e. does the integral
$$\int_{[0,1]}T_t\,dt$$
converge in $\mathcal{B}(L^2(\mathbb{R}))$?

*Thoughts:* Since each operator $T_t$ has norm, the question is whether $\gamma$ is [strongly measurable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_measurable_function). In particular, there is a question of whether there exists a subset of $J\subseteq[0,1]$ of measure $1$ such that $\gamma(J)$ is separable. Certainly $\gamma([0,1])$ is not separable, and I suspect that no such subset $J$ exists, but I'm not sure how to show this.

Comment: I think $\gamma$ does not have separable range, so it is not strongly measurable. There are different notions of measurability and integrability for Banach valued functions so the question is  a bit vague.

Comment: Indeed, so it doesn't seem to be Bochner-integrable. That seems fairly satisfactory to me.

Comment: If it is not strongly measurable it is not Bochner intergable. Can you show that $\gamma $ does not have separable range? What is $\|T_t-T_s\|$ for $t \neq s$?

Comment: There is an uncountable family of disjoint open sets in the range of $\gamma$, so it's not separable. On the other hand, how do we know that $\gamma$ isn't equal to a separably-valued map $\gamma_0$ on a subset $J\subseteq[0,1]$ of full measure?

Comment: The fact that $\gamma$ is not continuous is an interesting observation. How do you prove that? (My view of this is to observe that the infinitesimal generator of $\gamma$ is the derivative operator $\frac{d}{dx}$, which is not bounded, hence the semigroup is not uniformly continuous).

Comment: Anyway, I would look in some book on semigroups, such as Goldstein or Engel-Nagel, I am sure you will find the answer to this question there.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I see, that's an interesting point. My thought was, just like Kavi Rama Murthy said, that $\|T_t-T_s\|$ is bounded below by a constant for $t\neq s$ (for example you can let $T_t-T_s$ act on a function supported on a very small piece of $\mathbb{R}$).

Answer (score 1):

**NOT AN ANSWER - EXTENDED COMMENT**.

This question suggested me the following formal manipulation. The semigroup $T_t$ can be written, formally, as
$$
T_t=e^{t\frac{\partial}{\partial x}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{t^n}{n!}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}.$$
Integrating in $t\in[0, 1]$, again formally, we obtain
$$
\int_0^1 T_t\, dt = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!(n+1)}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}.$$
It seems to me that the comments are suggesting that $T_t$ is NOT integrable. Therefore this last expression should make no sense. But I cannot see why.